# Performing a join operation through broadcast in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to join a big stream with a much smaller stream. I would like to broadcast the smaller stream and then connect it to the bigger stream.

However I am not sure how to deal with storing the broadcasted patterns and in the `processElement method` how to look up the matching pattern and then combining the two elements.

Edit:
I have managed to have a prototype of broadcast joining using the following snippet. I adapted the normal join found in the official training repository: https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/release-1.13/rides-and-fares/src/solution/scala/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/ridesandfares/scala/RidesAndFaresSolution.scala

This seems to be working but I am unsure if my logic is correct.

```
//The main function has been abbreviated for ease of reading
def main(){
    val rides = env
      .addSource(rideSourceOrTest(new TaxiRideGenerator()))
      .filter { ride => ride.isStart }
//      .keyBy { ride => ride.rideId }

    val fares = env
      .addSource(fareSourceOrTest(new TaxiFareGenerator()))

    val broadcastStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor[Long,TaxiFare]("fares_broadcast",classOf[Long],classOf[TaxiFare])
    val faresBroadcast: BroadcastStream[TaxiFare] = fares
      .broadcast(broadcastStateDescriptor)

    val result: DataStream[(TaxiRide,TaxiFare)] = rides
      .connect(faresBroadcast)
      .process(new BroadcastJoin())
}

class BroadcastJoin() extends BroadcastProcessFunction[TaxiRide,TaxiFare,(TaxiRide,TaxiFare)]{//IN1, IN2, OUT。 That is, non broadcast stream type, broadcast stream type and output stream type
    //Broadcast state descriptor
    private lazy val broadcastStateDescriptor =  new MapStateDescriptor[Long,TaxiFare]("fares_broadcast",classOf[Long],classOf[TaxiFare])

    //Process the broadcast stream element, value is the broadcast stream element passed in, and the modifiable broadcast state can be obtained through CTX
    override def processBroadcastElement(value: TaxiFare, ctx: BroadcastProcessFunction[TaxiRide,TaxiFare,(TaxiRide,TaxiFare)]#Context, out: Collector[(TaxiRide,TaxiFare)]): Unit = {
      val broadcast_status: BroadcastState[Long,TaxiFare] = ctx.getBroadcastState(broadcastStateDescriptor)
      if(broadcast_status.contains(value.rideId)){
        broadcast_status.remove(value.rideId)
      }
      broadcast_status.put ( value.rideId , value) // add the broadcast stream element to the broadcast state, which will be saved in local memory
    }

    //Handle non broadcast stream elements. Value is the non broadcast stream element passed in. Only read-only broadcast status can be obtained through CTX
    override def processElement(value: TaxiRide, ctx: BroadcastProcessFunction[TaxiRide,TaxiFare,(TaxiRide,TaxiFare)]#ReadOnlyContext, out: Collector[(TaxiRide,TaxiFare)]): Unit = {
      //Read broadcast status
      val broadcast_status: ReadOnlyBroadcastState[Long, TaxiFare] = ctx.getBroadcastState(broadcastStateDescriptor)
      if(broadcast_status.contains(value.rideId)) {
        val foundMatch = broadcast_status.get(value.rideId)
        out.collect((value, foundMatch)) //Send out the desired results
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hi Peter! I just updated my post with more meaningful information. I can successfully join two streams using the broadcasting method, but I would like to know if I have any issues with my implementation

Answer (score 0):

For example, your high volume stream might be financial transactions, and the low volume broadcast stream might be foreign exchange rates from various currencies to USD. Your goal might be to normalize all transactions to USD.

You will need to describe whatever data it is that you broadcast as a map from keys to values.

In this case you could broadcast a map where the key is a currency (e.g., EUR), and the value is the latest exchange rate from that currency to USD. Then in the processBroadcastElement method of your BroadcastProcessFunction you would store these exchange rates, and in the processElement method you would lookup the relevant exchange rate for the incoming transaction from the broadcast state.

(This may not be the best way to accomplish this particular goal -- it's just the first example that came to mind.)

Comment: Hello David, thanks a lot for your input. I started playing around with the training repository, and I modified the RidesAndFares exercise to use broadcast joining instead of plain join. In my case I changed the FareGenerator so that it only creates 20 samples. I managed to successfully broadcast join using the snippet I pasted above, and indeed I have as a result 20 tuples.

However if I try going the other route, by first keying the main stream and using KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction instead (I have a very similar implementation as what I have pasted), I always receive less than 20 tuples.

Comment: A problem I see is that you are ignoring any taxi rides that arrive before the initial broadcast. One solution would be to add an open() method that initializes the broadcast state so that there is always something available to join with.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right. I was observing a behaviour where I am missing data, and I thought it had something to do with watermark configuration or something similar. Could you please concretely show me how to do this initialisation in the open method more concretely?